# Normal Distribution bayesAB - negative mean values

Tags: r, bayesian

```
A_norm <- rnorm(300, 5, 2)
B_norm <- rnorm(300, -5, 2)

AB2 <- bayesTest(A_norm, B_norm,
             priors = c('mu' = 5, 'lambda' = 1, 'alpha' = 3, 'beta' = 1), 
             distribution = 'normal')

plot(AB2)
summary(AB2)
```

Using the above code, `summary(AB2)` shows that the probability of A > B is equal to 0, however when I look at the posterior plots of mu for A and B (`plot(AB2)`) - the distribution of A looks to be always greater than B with no overlap. I think it has to do with comparing two normal distributions with both a positive and negative mean respectively. However, I cant understand why this would affect it. Can someone help me understand?